# Wordpress New Post via XMLRPC

Tags: xml, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to post to wordpress using xmlrpc, however, I don't know how to put categories and tags into the xml.

Does anyone matter to know how to do it?

Please see below how I'm doing the xml file. It is working fine, but without categories nor tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>metaWeblog.newPost</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <int>1</int>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>username</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>password</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <struct>
      <member>
        <name>wp_slug</name>
        <value><string></string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>wp_password</name>
        <value><string></string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>wp_page_parent_id</name>
        <value><int></int></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>wp_page_order</name>
        <value><int></int></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>wp_author_id</name>
        <value><int>1</int></value>
      </member>    
      <member>
        <name>title</name>
        <value><string>title</string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>description</name>
        <value><string>description</string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>mt_excerpt</name>
        <value><string></string></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>mt_text_more</name>
        <value><string></string></value>
      </member>    
      <member>
        <name>mt_allow_comments</name>
        <value><int>1</int></value>
      </member>  
      <member>
        <name>mt_allow_pings</name>
        <value><int>1</int></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>mt_allow_pings</name>
        <value><datetime></datetime></value>
      </member>
    </struct>  
    <param>
      <value>
        <bool>true</bool>
      </value>
    </param>    
  </params>  
</methodCall>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: This is *very* WP-specific and would probably do well at [WP.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[...]
<struct>
<member>
<name>categories</name>
<value><array><data><value>Category 1</value><value>Category 2</value></data></array></value>
</member>
[...]
```

...Replacing "1,2,3,4,5" with a comma-separated list of the categories the post belongs to.

From: http://www.juust.org/index.php/metaweblog-newpost-posting-to-wordpress-from-word/2009/10/

(Edit: I think I misread that; it's asking for the category names in their own "value" tags, not a comma-separated list.)

Comment: Hi Aendrew, It is exactly what I want.. Thank you!
For Tags, I created another member inside the struct and named this as mt_keywords.

Comment: Glad to help! It'd be great if you could then mark this answer as accepted by clicking the little green checkmark. Thanks!